# What is the relationship between AudioFileReader.Length and AudioFileReader.TotalTime in N Audio?

Tags: c#, audio, bitmap, naudio, waveform

I am writing a small app to create a waveform from an MP3 file. I create a bitmap, but at the moment just make it wildly too big (12800 pixels) so I can ensure the whole wavelength fits on.

```
var samples = reader.Length / (reader.WaveFormat.Channels * reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8);
Bitmap bim = new Bitmap(12800, 200);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bim);
```

This works, but I end up with a bunch of white space at the end of the waveform image:

[image]

I want to do this more intelligently, and use a variable calculated by the number of samples to ensure the bitmap width matches the length of the waveform (i.e. no white space).

What I really want to do is to tie the width to time - so 1 second is (for example) 15 pixels.

I can get the duration using `AudioFileReader.TotalTime`, but I can't work out how this correlates to `AudioFileReader.Length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Length` is in bytes, `TotalTime` converts that into a `TimeSpan` for you using the `AverageBytesPerSecond` of the `WaveFormat`